# onClick handler does not update innerHTML of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an onClick function that is attached to rows of a table by the characterID that is provided from an array of objects (instantiated from a constructor function).

I'm using styled-components, hence the odd tag names further down.

Here's the function:

```
    //this is an onClick function for use in record rows in the JSX populated table for characters  
    function barkCharData(idIn){
        console.log("==========================");
        
        try{
            //Get the fields...
            let idField = document.getElementById("txt_idField");
            let nameField = document.getElementsByName("first_name_field");

            //Set the fields
            idField.innerHTML = String(ar_charBin[idIn-1].id);
            console.log("\n---> idField: "+idField);
            console.log("---> idField.innerHTML: "+idField.innerHTML+"\n")
            
            nameField.innerHTML = String(ar_charBin[idIn-1].id);
            console.log("\n---> nameField: "+nameField);
            console.log("---> nameField.innerHTML: "+nameField.innerHTML+"\n")

        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log("Pants were shat in the 'barkCharData' function [line 72]:\n\t" +error)
        }                    
    }
}
```

I can access each objects properties fine because they're all stored in an array called `ar_charBin`. Had them console logged earlier with no issues.

The problem I'm having is that I want to put these properties in to disabled text boxes.

These are defined as JSX here:

```
export const ExpTable = () => {

    let Char1 = new char_Obj(1,"Saloth", "Saar", 45, "Male", "Dragonborn", "Sorcerer", 10);
    let Char2 = new char_Obj(2,"Kaedwen", "Isaani", 36, "Male", "Dragonborn", "Sorcerer", 8); 
    let Char3 = new char_Obj(3,"Euridice", "Swiftblade", 23, "Female", "Human", "Bard", 5);
    
    //array to store characters
    let ar_charBin = [];
    
    //push all chars into the array
    ar_charBin.push(Char1, Char2, Char3);

    return(
        <>
...table head stuff... 

                    <tbody>
                        {ar_charBin.map((character) => (
                        <TableRow key={character.id} onClick={() => barkCharData(character.id)}>
                            <td>{character.full_name}</td>
                            <td>Level {character.level} {character.classType}</td>
                        </TableRow> 
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>

                <Wrapper>
                <h2>Object elements</h2>
                <p>These fields should update with object<br/>attributes when the records above are clicked</p>

                <input type="text" id="txt_idField" name ="id_field" placeholder="ID"/>
                <input type="text" id="txt_fNameField" name ="first_name_field" placeholder="First Name" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_sNameField" placeholder="Second Name" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_ageField" placeholder="Age" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_cNameField" placeholder="Full Name" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_genderField" placeholder="Gender" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_raceField" placeholder="Race" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_classField" placeholder="Class" disabled={true} />
                <input type="text" id="txt_levelField" placeholder="Level" disabled={true} />
            </Wrapper>
            </Wrapper>
        </>
    )
```

So in the onClick function, it doesn't update the innerHTML of any element. Not sure why. I've tried inputting strings in VScode and in the page when I run `npm start` too but nothing seems to change them.

Screenshot of the app:

[image: App]
Looked for solutions but got nowhere so far. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

React avoids re-rendering unless state was changed. Since all of the changes happen on local variable scale and no state updates were caused by your onClick event, React will keep all HTML as it was.
Try holding the ID of the selected character in the state and hopefully you should see some updates of HTML.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).